# Apache serve a web page in different languages

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration

I want to serve a web page in different languages depending on where the user comes from.
Eg. `www.mysite.com/fr` if the user is from France and www.mysite/es if the user is from Spain.
Also it would be accepeted `www.fr.mysite.com` and `www.es.mysite.com`.

I'm not refering to this: [Content Negotiation - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/es/content-negotiation.html).
I don't want it to be shown like this: `www.mysite.com/home.es.html`.

Comment: Are you hosting static HTML files or some sort of PHP or CGI, content management, etc?

Comment: Can you clarify "from France"? Browsers send the user's language preferences, this might be more useful than the geographic location?

Comment: paris france europe

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the URL to whatever you want with mod_rewrite:

[mod_rewrite - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Something like user request `www.mysite/es` and Apache will internally redirected to `www.mysite.com/home.es.html`, The user will never have to see `www.mysite.com/home.es.html`, it will look like the URL is `www.mysite/es` but in reality it's at `www.mysite.com/home.es.html`.

Comment: Some of this answer is confusing, and unclear. Consider expanding upon your proposed solution, and using code escapes and block formatting.